# alter table for scope

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, object-relational-model

This is the code I found on a course

```
 create type employee_type AS OBJECT
    ( empno number(4),
    ename varchar2(40),
    dept_ref REF department_type)
    /
    create table employee of employee_type
    ( empno PRIMARY KEY )
    /
    create type department_type AS OBJECT
    ( deptno number(2),
    dname varchar2(20),
    loc varchar(20))
    /
    create table employee of employee_type
    ( empno PRIMARY KEY )
    /
    create table department of department_type
    ( deptno PRIMARY KEY )
    /
    alter table employee
    add (scope for (dept_ref) is department)
    /
```

I don't understand why we need to alter employee table to add scope for to department table, I mean dept_ref has been referred to department_type already and department table is consisted of department_type object, what is the add scope statment do?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm), the purpose is to say that `dept_ref` in `employee` has to refer, specifically, to a `department`, and not to *any other* table that may be of `department_type` type.

See **REF Columns: Examples**:

> The `dept` column can store references to objects of `dept_t` stored in any table. If you would like to restrict the references to point only to objects stored in the `departments` table, then you could do so by adding a scope constraint on the `dept` column as follows ...

(People, apparently, love drawing examples from the domain of employees and departments)

Comment: Unless the example comes from homework, in which case it's always COURSES and STUDENTS :)